# Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "progress"

Tags: sql-server-2008, linked-server, openedge, progress-db

I'm trying to select some data from a Progress Database using an openquery on SQL Server 2008 R2, but I'm getting this error message.

```
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "progress" reported an error. The provider reported an unexpected catastrophic failure.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "progress".
```

I did some tests and I discovered that the problem is with a specif column which is a varchar column. The column has around 30 columns and for them the select works fine.
This is my query:

```
SELECT * from openquery(progress, 'select DescricaoProduto from MP.pub.IMPproduto')
```

I tried to do some different selects but none of them worked. For example:

```
SELECT * from openquery(progress, 'select Cast(DescricaoProduto as char(100)) as DescricaoProduto from MP.pub.IMPproduto')
```

Any idea about what to do?

Answer (score 3):

Progress data is **all** variable length.  Progress applications routinely "over-stuff" fields.  SQL tools often object to that.  The Progress db maintains a SQL-WIDTH attribute which can be updated using the "dbtool" utility provided by Progress.  If you are going to pull data from a Progress database you **must** use this tool periodically.

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P24496?q=how+to+use+dbtool+to+modify+sql-width&l=en_US&c=Product_Group%3AOpenEdge&fs=Search&pn=1

The easy path is to start PROENV (found in the OpenEdge program group) then run "dbtool dbname" and select option 2.

Or you can use the following SQL:

ALTER TABLE  ALTER COLUMN  SET PRO_SQL_WIDTH  ;

if you know which table & column is causing the problem and you do not need to scan everything.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to work around the problem is to use SUBSTRING, like so:

```
SELECT * from openquery(progress, 'select substring(DescricaoProduto,1,100) as DescricaoProduto from MP.pub.IMPproduto')
```

So, if the column is defined as 30 characters and the column contains 50, substring(col, 1,50) will actually retrieve all 50 characters.